# Error During composer-cli installation for Hyperledger

Tags: node.js, npm-install, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to install composer-cli 0.20 but everytime I get this error

> [..................] - fetchMetadata: sill fetchPackageMetaData error for sjcl@1.0.7 zlib: unexpected end of fil

I am using VSCode on Windows 10, my node version is 11.6.0 and npm version is 6.5.0.
This is what the log file says:

> 386 verbose node v11.6.0
>
> 387 verbose npm  v6.5.0
>
> 388 error code Z_BUF_ERROR
>
> 389 error errno -5
>
> 390 error zlib: unexpected end of file 391 verbose exit [ -5, true ]

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the issue you are experiencing, Hyperledger Composer is not supported on windows, nor is node 11 supported on any Hyperledger Composer supported platform, as node 8 is the only supported version of node. I recommend you use a hypervisor such as HyperV, VirtualBox or VMWare to load a supported version of linux for Hyerledger Composer.
see https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs for more information about pre-reqs (note that ubuntu bionic 18.04 although not listed will work as well)

Answer (score -1):

I've been running Composer on Windows 7 with VirtualBox and a few tweaks, so I don't think it is a problem. I think the problem is with the package you're installing. Try creating an empty project and adding sjcl@1.0.7. You can also use a package sniffer and check what's going on during the install.